# Why when updating the label to display the timer counting backward the time in the label is jumping: 50 then 40 then 50 then 39 then 50 then 38?

Tags: c#, winforms

I can't figure out why it's jumping like this.

I want to display on the label the timer time counting back, and the label control is in form1 designer, so I use the Radar class constructors to get the label and use it in the Radar class.

but when running the application the timer goes down backward fine but when I start the process by clicking the button in form1 then the timer start showing this "jumps"

this is in form1 how I start the download process and then the timer start with the "jumps" :

```
private async void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Display folder selection dialog
    using (var folderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        if (folderDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Waiting for download to start";
            txtFolder.Text = folderDialog.SelectedPath;
            radar = new Radar(lblNextTimeDownload, txtFolder.Text);
            radar.ProgressChanged += Radar_ProgressChanged;
            radar.DownloadCompleted += Radar_DownloadCompleted;

            // Subscribe to the DownloadStarted event
            radar.DownloadStarted += Radar_DownloadStarted;

            // Start asynchronous download
            await radar.DownloadAndProcessImagesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

What have I tried so far:

I declare at the top the Timer the DateTime and the Label:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
private DateTime nextDownloadTime;

private Label lblNextTimeDownload;
```

then Init the timer:

```
private void InitializeTimer()
{
    timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000; // 1 second interval for more frequent updates
    timer.Tick += TimerTick; // Use Tick event instead of Elapsed
    nextDownloadTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5); // Set initial next download time
    UpdateNextDownloadLabel(); // Update the label initially
    timer.Start(); // Start the timer
}
```

then updating in the timer tick event:

```
private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Same logic as TimerElapsed
    TimeSpan remainingTime = nextDownloadTime - DateTime.Now;

    lblNextTimeDownload.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        lblNextTimeDownload.Text = "Next download in: " + remainingTime.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
    });

    if (remainingTime <= TimeSpan.Zero)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        PrepareLinks();
        DownloadAndProcessImagesAsync().Wait();
        nextDownloadTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

the full code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Radar_Images
{
    public class Radar
    {
        public List<string> Links { get; private set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> LinksAndFileNames { get; private set; }
        public string Folder { get; private set; }

        private string defaultLink;
        private DateTime current;

        public event EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventArgs> ProgressChanged;
        public event EventHandler<AsyncCompletedEventArgs> DownloadCompleted;

        public event EventHandler DownloadStarted;

        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ImageProcessed;

        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
        private DateTime nextDownloadTime;

        private Label lblNextTimeDownload;

        public Radar(Label lblNextTimeDownload, string inputFolder)
        {
            this.lblNextTimeDownload=  lblNextTimeDownload;
            InitializeRadar(inputFolder);
            InitializeTimer();
        }

        public Radar(Label lblNextTimeDownload)
        {
            this.lblNextTimeDownload = lblNextTimeDownload;
            InitializeRadar(null);
            InitializeTimer();
        }

        private void InitializeTimer()
        {
            timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 1000; // 1 second interval for more frequent updates
            timer.Tick += TimerTick; // Use Tick event instead of Elapsed
            nextDownloadTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5); // Set initial next download time
            UpdateNextDownloadLabel(); // Update the label initially
            timer.Start(); // Start the timer
        }

        private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Same logic as TimerElapsed
            TimeSpan remainingTime = nextDownloadTime - DateTime.Now;

            lblNextTimeDownload.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                lblNextTimeDownload.Text = "Next download in: " + remainingTime.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
            });

            if (remainingTime <= TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                timer.Stop();
                PrepareLinks();
                DownloadAndProcessImagesAsync().Wait();
                nextDownloadTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
                timer.Start();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateNextDownloadLabel()
        {
            TimeSpan remainingTime = nextDownloadTime - DateTime.Now;
            lblNextTimeDownload.Text = "Next download in: " + remainingTime.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
        }

        private void InitializeRadar(string inputFolder)
        {
            defaultLink = "https://ims.gov.il/sites/default/files/ims_data/map_images/IMSRadar4GIS/IMSRadar4GIS_";
            Folder = inputFolder ?? Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            current = RoundDown(DateTime.Now, 1);
            PrepareLinks();
        }

        public List<string> PrepareLinks()
        {
            LinksAndFileNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Links = new List<string>();

            GenerateRadarLinks();

            // Exclude links for files that already exist in the folder
            var existingFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Folder, "*.png").Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).ToList();
            Links = Links.Where(link => !existingFiles.Contains(LinksAndFileNames[link])).ToList();

            return Links;
        }

        private void GenerateRadarLinks()
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(Folder + "\\Dates"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Folder + "\\Dates");
            }

            using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(Folder + "\\Dates\\" + "dates.txt"))
            using (StreamWriter ww = new StreamWriter(Folder + "\\Dates\\" + "datesTime.txt"))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
                {
                    var date = current.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
                    ww.WriteLine(current.ToString());
                    w.WriteLine(date);
                    var link = defaultLink + date + "_0.png";
                    Links.Add(link);
                    LinksAndFileNames.Add(link, current.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm"));
                    current = current.AddMinutes(-1);
                }
            }
        }

        private DateTime RoundDown(DateTime dt, int NearestMinuteInterval)
        {
            return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute / NearestMinuteInterval * NearestMinuteInterval, 0);
        }

        public async Task DownloadAndProcessImagesAsync()
        {
            await DownloadImagesAsync();
            await ProcessDownloadedImagesAsync();
        }

        public async Task DownloadImagesAsync()
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                int totalFiles = Links.Count;
                int completedFiles = 0;

                foreach (var link in Links)
                {
                    var fileName = LinksAndFileNames[link];
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(Folder, fileName + ".png");

                    try
                    {
                        var response = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(link);

                        // Signal that the actual download has started
                        DownloadStarted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

                        await Task.Run(() => File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, response));
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // Handle download failure
                    }

                    completedFiles++;
                    int progressPercentage = (int)((double)completedFiles / totalFiles * 100);

                    // Report progress
                    ProgressChanged?.Invoke(this, new ProgressChangedEventArgs(progressPercentage, null));
                }

                // Notify completion
                DownloadCompleted?.Invoke(this, new AsyncCompletedEventArgs(null, false, null));
            }
        }

        private async Task ProcessDownloadedImagesAsync()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                foreach (var link in Links)
                {
                    var fileName = LinksAndFileNames[link];
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(Folder, fileName + ".png");

                    // Check if the file exists before processing
                    if (File.Exists(filePath))
                    {
                        // Process the downloaded image
                        RadarImagesConvertor convertor = new RadarImagesConvertor(filePath, Folder);

                        // You might want to add an event in RadarImagesConvertor to signal completion
                        // and handle it here if needed.

                        // Signal that the image has been processed
                        ImageProcessed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Handle the case where the file does not exist
                        Console.WriteLine($"File not found: {filePath}");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't pass UI Components around. That won't make you happy. I'd not even recommend to use Events in this case. You are already async, so maybe consider using `IProgress<T>` .

Comment: This line is blocking: `DownloadAndProcessImagesAsync().Wait();` - Try changing the `TimerTick()` method to `async void` (the void is unavoidable - no pun intended) and then use `await DownloadAndProcessImagesAsync()`. However I think there are likely other issues than this one lurking in your code...

Comment: You are making the same mistake over and over (since, given the code you have here, I assume you're the same person posting questions with different accounts). You have a non-threaded Timer that uses `Invoke()` for no reason, which is already highly problematic. Then you stop the Timer, call `Wait()` on an async method (very bad), and you ask why the time update loses beats. It's because you coded it like that. Don't do anything in the Timer event. Offload that work entirely. If you need to avoid concurrency, enqueue the work and process one at the time

Comment: Just because something is "async" does not mean it will not use the UI thread. If there is to much being scheduled on the UI thread, your timer ticks can get crowded out, and your UI will feel slow. Run a profiler to check what the UI thread is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the "jumping around" by running your code and in the process of doing that immediately saw that Fildor's observation is spot on (as are the other comments). The `Radar` class has no business messing with the UI. It is (or should be) a stateful provider of the service: asynchronous downloading and processing of a set of images/links.

The client of this service is `MainForm`. It might make better sense as the owner of the progress and countdown UI elements for it to be the one keeping track of the interval and calling `Radar.ExecuteAsync()`. Starting and stopping a timer is another thing that can be bad for business. Please don't use a timer. One alternate approach is an async loop that, depending on `Radar.State` will either show and update a countdown label *or* show and update a progress bar. With this approach, `MainForm` only needs to know *when* `Radar.State` or `Radar.Progress` change which is a function of implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the `Radar` class.

---

**Main Form**

Example of keeping track of the interval using an async loop.

[image: mainform handles radar states]

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    TimeSpan UpdateInterval { get; } = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);  
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _downloadProgress = new ProgressBar
        {
            Location = lblNextTimeDownload.Location,
            Size = lblNextTimeDownload.Size,
            Value = 0,
        };
    }
    readonly ProgressBar _downloadProgress;
```

Async loop to update countdown

```
    DateTime _nextDownloadTime = DateTime.Now;
    private async Task updateLabelAsync()
    {
        while (!Disposing)
        {
            TimeSpan countdown = _nextDownloadTime - DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.99);
            if (countdown <= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.99))
            {
                lblNextTimeDownload.Visible = false;
                _downloadProgress.Visible = true;
                await _radar.ExececuteAsync();
                Debug.Assert(_radar.State == RadarState.Waiting, "Expecting Radar to reset its state.");
                _nextDownloadTime = DateTime.Now + UpdateInterval;
            }
            else
            {
                lblNextTimeDownload.Visible = true;
                _downloadProgress.Visible = false;
                lblNextTimeDownload.Text = "Next download in: " + countdown.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
                await Task.Delay(500);
            }
        }
    }
```

Subscribe to PropertyChanged notifications

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        lblNextTimeDownload.Visible = false;
        Controls.Add(_downloadProgress);
        _radar.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {            
            switch (e.PropertyName)
            {
                case nameof(_radar.State):
                    // Update the title bar
                    if (!Disposing) BeginInvoke(() => Text = $"Radar - {_radar.State}");
                    break;
                case nameof(_radar.Progress):
                    // Update the progress bar
                    if (!Disposing) BeginInvoke(() => _downloadProgress.Value = _radar.Progress);
                    break;
            }
        };
        // Start timer
        Task task = updateLabelAsync();
        Disposed += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            await task;
            task.Dispose();
        };
    }
```

Init `Radar` class.

```
    Radar _radar = new Radar(Path.Combine
    (
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
        Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name
    ));
}
```

---

**Radar class**

Modified to be a stateful service that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
public enum RadarState 
{ 
    Waiting, 
    Initializing,
    Downloading,
    DownloadCompleted, 
    ImageProcessing, 
    ImageProcessed, 
}
public class Radar : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Radar(string? inputFolder = null) =>
        Folder = inputFolder ?? Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    public string Folder { get; }
    public string DefaultLink { get; }  = "https://ims.gov.il/sites/default/files/ims_data/map_images/IMSRadar4GIS/IMSRadar4GIS_";
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public RadarState State
    {
        get => _state;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_state, value))
            {
                _state = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    RadarState _state = default;
    public int Progress
    {
        get => _progress;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_progress, value))
            {
                _progress = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    int _progress = default;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string? propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public async Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        State = RadarState.Initializing;
        PrepareLinks();
        await DownloadImagesAsync();
        await ProcessDownloadedImagesAsync();
        State = RadarState.Waiting;
    }
    public List<string> Links { get; } = new List<string>();
    public Dictionary<string, string> LinksAndFileNames { get; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public void PrepareLinks()
    {
        LinksAndFileNames.Clear();
        Links.Clear();

        GenerateRadarLinks();

        // Exclude links for files that already exist in the folder
        foreach (var existing in Directory.GetFiles(Folder, "*.png").Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension))
        {
            if(Links.FirstOrDefault(_=>_.Contains(existing)) is string link)
            {
                Links.Remove(link);
            }
        }
    }

    private void GenerateRadarLinks()
    {
        DateTime current = RoundDown(DateTime.Now, 1);

        if (!Directory.Exists(Folder + "\\Dates"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Folder + "\\Dates");
        }

        using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(Folder + "\\Dates\\" + "dates.txt"))
        using (StreamWriter ww = new StreamWriter(Folder + "\\Dates\\" + "datesTime.txt"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            {
                var date = current.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
                ww.WriteLine(current.ToString());
                w.WriteLine(date);
                var link = DefaultLink + date + "_0.png";
                Links.Add(link);
                LinksAndFileNames.Add(link, current.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm"));
                current = current.AddMinutes(-1);
            }
        }
    }
    private DateTime RoundDown(DateTime dt, int NearestMinuteInterval) =>
        new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute / NearestMinuteInterval * NearestMinuteInterval, 0);

    private async Task DownloadImagesAsync()
    {
        Progress = 0;
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            int totalFiles = Links.Count;
            int completedFiles = 0;
            if (Links.Any())
            {
                // Signal that the actual download has started
                State = RadarState.Downloading;

                foreach (var link in Links)
                {
                    var fileName = LinksAndFileNames[link];
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(Folder, fileName + ".png");

                    // Mock Download
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));

                    completedFiles++;
                    Progress = (int)((double)completedFiles / totalFiles * 100);
                }
            }
            // Notify completion
            State = RadarState.DownloadCompleted;
        }
        // Ensure Progress has gone to the end, and
        // allow time to view the result.
        Progress = 100;
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
    }

    private async Task ProcessDownloadedImagesAsync()
    {
        Progress = 0;
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Links.Count; i++) 
            {
                var link = Links[i];
                var fileName = LinksAndFileNames[link];
                var filePath = Path.Combine(Folder, fileName + ".png");

                // Check if the file exists before processing
                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    State = RadarState.ImageProcessing;

                    // Process the downloaded image
                    // RadarImagesConvertor convertor = new RadarImagesConvertor(filePath, Folder);

                    // Signal that the image has been processed
                    State = RadarState.ImageProcessed;
                }
                else
                {
#if DEBUG
                    // No files exist in this mock setting, so 
                    // exercise the state to make sure things work,
                    State = RadarState.ImageProcessing;
                    // Mock the image processing time
                    await Task.Delay(50);

                    // Signal that the image has been processed
                    State = RadarState.ImageProcessed;
                    await Task.Delay(50);
#endif


                    // Handle the case where the file does not exist
                    Console.WriteLine($"File not found: {filePath}");
                }
                Progress = (int)(i/(Links.Count * 0.01));
            }
        });       
        // Ensure Progress has gone to the end, and
        // allow time to view the result.
        Progress = 100;
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no progresschanged for radar.  radar.ProgressChanged += Radar_ProgressChanged;
radar.DownloadCompleted += Radar_DownloadCompleted; no ProgressChanged and no DownloadCompleted also the Radar instance should get string so instead radar = new Radar(lblNextTimeDownload); i did radar = new Radar(lblNextTimeDownload.Text);

Comment: Uses property changed of `Progress` to update. Try running it. [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/radar-processes-image-timer.git).

Comment: going to try it the link you provided the clone

Comment: If the nullable thing gets in the way, you can remove the `?` without consequence here and other places like it:  `public Radar(string inputFolder = null)`.

Comment: just one knowledge question, in your clone project the progressbar is not getting to 100% the green bar not getting to the end.  what if I wanted to display to the user that it's getting to 100% when download completed?  or it's not matter?

Comment: Good suggestion I'm editing the answer to include it. I agree that it's reassuring for the progress bar to go all the way to the end. What I like to do (especially when there's 'double' arithmetic involved in the progress calculation) is to explicitly set Progress to 100 before returning then wait for a couple of seconds for everyone to "ooo" and "aaah". Try this snippet as the very last line of `DownloadImagesAsync()` and `ProcessDownloadedImagesAsync()` and see whether it helps: `Progress = 100; await Task.Delay(2000);`